# How to use UserStoppedTypingBehavior

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning xamarinforms. I trying to display the search value in my code behind using UserStoppedTypingBehavior

My xalm looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:pv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView" xmlns:sharedcustom="clr-namespace:xxx.MyClasses.SharedCustom" xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:xxx.MyValueConverter" xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
x:Class="xxx.MyPages.MyNews.MyLeafNews">


<Grid>

<Entry   x:Name="VariableSearchNews"  >

    <Entry.Behaviors>
    <xct:UserStoppedTypingBehavior
    Command="{Binding SearchNewsCommand}"
    StoppedTypingTimeThreshold="2"
    MinimumLengthThreshold="2"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>


</Entry>

</Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

My code behind looks like this :

```
public ICommand SearchNewsCommand { get; }

public MyLeafNews()
{
InitializeComponent();

SearchNewsCommand = new Command<string>(onSearchNews);
this.BindingContext = this;

}
void onsearchNews(string mysearch)
{
// Display the search text here 
Console.WriteLine("The user has wrote :"+mysearch);
}
```

What I would like :

Using User Stopped Typing Behavior (Xamarin Community Toolkit), I would like to lunch the function `onsearchNews(string mysearch)`in order to display what the user tapped

I am looking for the equivalent of this with UserStoppedTypingBehavior :

```
void OnSearcMyNews(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
//Here I can get text entered by the user 
// I would like to do the same with my function onsearchNews 
    using UserStoppedTypingBehavior
    //How to get onsearchNew string parameter that contain the search text ?
    var searchTerm = e.NewTextValue;

    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you have defined `SearchNewsCommand` but have not assigned anything to it

Comment: I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

there is a sample for this [here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Behaviors/UserStoppedTypingBehaviorPage.xaml), and the docs for `Command` are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#using-command-parameters)

you need to assign a value to your command, otherwise it will do nothing

```
SearchNewsCommand = new Command<string>(onSearchNews);
```

Comment: I do not see the value tapped in Console.WriteLine("Display the value tapped :"+mysearch);

Comment: have you set the BindingContext for your page?

Comment: the variable mysearch is supposed to be the tapped entry by the user

Comment: That does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: not I do not set it the binding contexte, How to do it please

Comment: Bindings will not work if you do not set the BindingContext

Comment: How to do it please ?

Comment: Have you read any documentation or looked at any examples?  This is a core part of using Xamarin Forms and is extremely well documented.  `this.BindingContext = this;`

Comment: I cannot see, how it will know that the text tapped can be read with variable string mysearch

Comment: I have no idea what "text tapped" means.  You specifically asked about using `UserStoppedTypingBehavior`.

Comment: Yes UserStoppedTypingBehavior is used to show the texte tapped in Entry when the user has finished to write in the entry

Comment: When a user is witting on the Entry object, I would like please to display the text entered by the user when he has stopped writting. This is why I would like to use UserStoppedTypingBehavior

Comment: the behavior's `Command` is bound to `SearchNewsCommand`, which calls `onsearchNews`.  If you need any further help, please [edit] your question to reflect the current state of the code

Comment: Yes it calls onsearchNews, How to get acces to the value written in the Entry

Comment: `onsearchNews` has a string parameter that should contain the search text

Comment: I have update the code with comment

Comment: It does not display when I use Console.WriteLine.  Console.WriteLine("The user has wrote :"+mysearch);

Comment: Please see my last comment about needing further help

Comment: Please find my code update with more comment and code

Comment: Yes this it, How to read this string parameter that contain the search text ?

Comment: Your edit does not show any changes to your code based on my answer

Comment: I have add code in the last part of my question

Comment: How to get onsearchNew string parameter that contain the search text ?

Comment: I want to see what your code looks like NOW so I can tell if you’re following the advice I have given you.  You instead posted the code for an event handler.

Comment: I have posted the code

Answer (score 1):

I had read the codes you provided and checked the official sample. You put the binding ICommand in the page.cs, but in the official sample, it is in the viewmodel. So I suggest you bind it by following the sample.

You can check the [viewmode.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/ViewModels/Behaviors/UserStoppedTypingBehaviorViewModel.cs) and the [page.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Behaviors/UserStoppedTypingBehaviorPage.xaml) in the sample.

Comment: I am trying this thanks

Comment: Waiting for your reply.@hk77

Comment: I have tried to implemented it but without success cause my project is already organized and mvvm search will be complicated because I am planned to add sql lite database search

Comment: But the viewmodel implement the base viewmodel and it's the official sample. @hk77